# Detecting device for debugging (ADB) does not work

Tags: android, adb

I've turned USB debugging on on my Archos 43 Internet Tablet (Android 2.3.26), but adb does not detect the device.

I have Kubuntu 11.04.

Output of shell command "lsusb":

```
michael@schlepptop777:~/.android_sdk/platform-tools$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e79:1411 Archos, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So my "Vendor ID" is 0e79, isn't it?

For the next step I've created the following file:

```
sudo kate /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
```

After that I've set the permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Then I've saved it and restarted udev:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

And after doing all that steps adb still does not display my device:

```
michael@schlepptop777:~/.android_sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
<empty line, because stackoverflow does not display this>
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting ADB as well, and then maybe disconnecting/reconnecting the device, rebooting the PC?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In some cases you also have to add vendor id to this file: `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE. 
0x0e79
```

Mind that this file might be overwritten when you upgrade SDK, so you might need to re-edit it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, I've just used the following tutorial: 
http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates.html?country=us&lang=en

(Section: ADB for Android Developers (ARCHOS Internet Tablet))

It's equal to your suggestion :)

Comment: And I always forget to add the "0x" before the id. It's so frustrating!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This did not work for me. Neither did the methods from other answers and other similar questions on StackExchange.

Answer (score 7):

Mageia 2

At first, I got something like:

```
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
```

Then I found I needed to do Settings | Applications | Development and Check the USB Debugging check box.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
???????????????? no permissions
```

Trying as root, I got:

```
$ su -l
# adb devices
List of devices attached 
???????????????? no permissions
```

Then I realized that adb was still running as regular user.  When, as root, I did:

```
# adb kill-server
# adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
A43-A44C0002-9BF80000-0C60C4CC-0D020027 offline
```

[ADB for Android Developers (ARCHOS Internet Tablet)](http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html) was helpful, except I ended up doing this as root:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="e79/*", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="e79", MODE="0666"
# udevadm control --reload-rules
# udevadm monitor
.
.
.
^C
```

The monitor command was helpful because it showed the device connects, disconnects, paths, etc.

I was then able to stop the server running as root, and start it as a regular user:

```
# adb kill-server
# exit
$ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
A43-A44C0002-9BF80000-0C60C4CC-0D020027 offline
```

The device will not work when "offline".  To fix that I had to reboot the Archos 43.

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
A43-A44C0002-9BF80000-0C60C4CC-0D020027 device
```

Though I doubt that these actions were required, to play it safe, after rebooting, I made sure to plug in the USB and select Charge Only before I set USB Debugging on.  I had also disabled WiFi and Syncing, but once it started working, adb would still connect with those being on.

At this point, downloading my app worked:

```
$ adb install bin/HelloWorld.apk 
2914 KB/s (157589 bytes in 0.052s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/HelloWorld.apk
Success
```

P.S.  The next day, knowing that everything worked the night before, I booted up my development system and tried to connect again.  This gave the "offline" status.  I disabled sync and WiFi, without rebooting the Archos 43, and then `adb devices` showed "device" status instead of "offline".  I am not sure what to make of that, but turning this stuff off could have significance after all.

Answer (score 2):

After doing the command `sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart` you have to reboot the system!
I know, it sounds like a windows behaviour, but I broke my head for 3 hours before discovering this thing.

Comment: Not true.  You probably needed to kill the running adb server.

Comment: true!! after almost half an hour testing all the other commands a reboot worked like a charm, thanks ;)

maybe there's other way but it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I borrowed a cable from an sd card reader and it wasn't working for adb, whilst it worked for the sd card reader.
I tried a new cable and low and behold adb devices recognises The device!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just like Aultbot, replacing the cable did the trick for me as well. Strange as I had been using the cable for several hours when it suddenly didn't work with ADB.

Also, make sure you accept the connection on the phone (new security function in Android 4)

Edit: Recently, there has been some issues regarding the adb service. If it is not started (check with netstat or similar or type "set ADB_TRACE=1" before running your adb command to get debug messages) then check threads dealing with that error message. A common issue is that the default port is in use by some other application (change port by typing "set ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT=12345" before the adb command).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 11.04, the only way I can get adb to connect to my Atrix is by changing the USB connection mode to "Windows Media Sync". Which is odd in the first place, but it's especially odd because ADB on windows won't connect when it's set to win media sync.
Or you can use wireless adb. There's a couple widgets that make it really easy to enable wifi adb. They show the ip address on the widget and everything. :)