# adb cannot find Android device (Trekstore Ventos 8 at Linux)

Tags: android, linux, adb

- developer option USB debugging is activated and show a notification when the tablet is connected via USB
- entry in /etc/udev/rules.d is there and has exactly the manufacturer code from lsusb
- other devices (Motorola Defy, Sony XPeria V, Samsung Galaxy S4 zoom) work fine
- tablet has just recently be totally wiped and reset
- /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc appear when tablet is connected, but mounting fails (no medium found)
- adb devices shows and empty list, adb shell fails, Eclipse immediately starts an emulator when an app is launched

How can I find out what is wrong? Is there any chance to get the USB debugging back on?

Comment: `udev` rule only fixes the device permissions. for `adb` to recognize the device you need to add its vendor ID to the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini http://stackoverflow.com/a/6485150/1778421

Comment: The ~/.android/adb_usb.ini is actually nowhere mentioned in the documentation, and the comment discourages from editing it. After editing, re-connecting the device, killing the adb server and starting it again it worked. Thank you.