# Phone Wiko Kite not found in ADB

Tags: android, linux, adb

Here is the problem : I have tried to connect my phone (Wiko Kite) on my computer (debian). I have installed adb with android SDK.

After following the basic configuration for linux ( as you can find on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484279/detecting-device-for-debugging-adb-does-not-work) ), and after a few reboots and such, my phone was still not recognised ( even though at this point, using a different phone was working perfectly).

The result of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 0a5c:e681 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:014c Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After removing my phone, only the first line disapears, so I'm guessing my vendor id is 0a5c, which I then manually added into ~/.android/adb_usb.ini. (and no, I did not forget to add 0x).

After that, I have two scenarios :

- If I run adb as a normal user, `adb devices` returns : 
  `List of devices attached 
  ????????????    no permissions`
- Otherwise, if I run adb as root, no device is found again.

  I'm guessing that the added line in adb_usb.ini can just not be checked when run as a normal user, which cause adb devices to return the error, but as root doesn't detect the associated phone and return an empty line, but I though it was worth mentioning.

-- EDIT --

As request, here is the content of /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules :

```
UBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",
ENV{PRODUCT}=="0a5c/*", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0a5c", MODE="0666"
```

Also, here is the result of the `dmsg` after plugging the phone :

```
[ 9164.536729] usb 4-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[ 9164.629954] usb 4-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=e681
[ 9164.629958] usb 4-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 9164.629961] usb 4-1.5: Product: KITE
[ 9164.629962] usb 4-1.5: Manufacturer: WIKO
[ 9164.629964] usb 4-1.5: SerialNumber: DI841434214624
[ 9164.630620] usb-storage 4-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9164.630692] scsi14 : usb-storage 4-1.5:1.0
[ 9165.630021] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-CD Gadget   0310 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 9165.630705] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 9165.632593] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: I doubt it can changed anything, but you may need the packet "usb_modeswitch" (in Fedora, I also have a "usb_modeswitch_data")

Comment: Thoses packets are already installed on my system, but thank you anyway

Comment: Could you run a ``dmesg`` before plugging your device, then plug it, then rerun a ``dmesg`` and see what is detected exactly ?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Comment: to fix the `????????????    no permissions` issue you need to set up an `udev` rule

Comment: I already had the udev rule setup, but for some reason the link you sent me fixed it. Though, now my adb_usb.ini needs to contain two times my vendor id, I'll have a closer look into it and post the explainations in an edit, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved following the steps of [this link](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html).

I do not understand what has fixed it yet, as I thought I did everything explained there, I will edit this answer once I figure this out.

Comment: even the smallest things could matter. like the difference in the rule file names `51-android.rules` vs `90-universal-android.rules`. `51` is sometimes too soon (`90-*` rule gets processed a bit later and works more reliably)

Answer (score 0):

You must create a udev rule to grant permissions to the USB device, as explained in the official developer docs - please see http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Likely you would want something like

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

And you will need to either `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` or similar (the command varies slightly by distribution/version) or else reboot.  Then re-plug the phone and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm going to edit my post, but I already added the special exception in my udev configuration, and it was not enough. See edited original post